# How to divide TextView into 2 Separate TextView in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem with TextView in Android

I am making an application like Facebook. In m.facebook.com, when I open it I see they do one thing specailly.

(Alice) is writing on (BackStreetBoy1010938920) wall

Because the width of Mobile screen is small so the real message like tha

(Alice) is writing on (BackStreet

Boy10101009393) wall

I guess they use TextView for  (BackStreetBoy1010938920) but I can't do like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you consider facebook, they open a webview on device, since the screen is small the  textbox width gets reduced, if you capture the same URL and open it in browser, it takes the complete width of the browser..................

Now consider the textView, if you make layout_height="wrap_content", it will take the height of the text and the width will be limited to whatever you provided............
Hope it helps a bit...........